# Float to String Round-Trip Test

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding, precision, ieee-754

I believe that 17 decimal places should be enough to correctly represent an 8-byte float, such that it is round-trip safe (converted to a string and back without any loss).

But in this test, the number can go as high as 23, and probably higher if you increase the number of iterations.

Is this a flawed test and why?
And how do you ensure a round-trip integrity of a float in Python?

```
def TestLoop():
    sFormat = ''
    success = True
    ff = [1.0/i for i in range(1,10000000)]
    for n in range(17, 31):
        sFormat = '{{:.{:d}f}}'.format(n)
        success = True
        for f in ff:
            if f != float(sFormat.format(f)):
                success = False
                break
        if success:
            return(n)
    return(-1)

n = TestLoop()   
print('Lossless with ', n, ' decimal places.')
```

[If an IEEE 754 double precision is converted to a decimal string with at least 17 significant digits and then converted back to double, then the final number must match the original.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my original test, I was operating on small numbers, so there were a lot of leading zeros, which are not significant digits. Floats require 17 **significant** digits to be represented correctly. By changing one line like so, I made the numbers larger and was able to succeed with only 16 digits after the decimal point.

```
ff = [10000000.0/i for i in range(1,10000000)]
```

The best approach seems to be to not use the `format()` at all, but use `repr()` or `str()` instead.
This code here succeeds:

```
def TestLoop():
    for i in range(1, 10000000):
        f = 1.0 / i
        if f != float(repr(f)):
            print('Failed.')
            return
    print('Succeeded.')
    return

TestLoop()
```

Another way that worked was to use 17 digits after the decimal point, but use the `g` formatter instead of `f`. This uses an exponent, so the leading zeros are eliminated.

```
if f != float('{:.17g}'.format(f)):
```

Comment: Yes, using `.17g` for the formatting is the right way to go here.  `.16e` would also work.  Don't use `str` on Python 2: it doesn't give enough digits.  But `repr` does. (In recent versions of Python 3, `str` and `repr` are identical for floats.)